# Multiplicative Order of a number as the modulo changes

Tags: group-theory, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

So it is a well-known fact that

$${\rm lcm}({\rm ord}_n(a), {\rm ord}_m(a)) ={\rm ord}_{mn}(a)$$

when $\gcd(m, n) = 1$. After lots of experiments, and I suspect that when $\gcd(m, n) \neq 1$,

$${\rm ord}_{mn}(a) = {\rm lcm}({\rm ord}_n(a), {\rm ord}_m(a)) \cdot \gcd(m, n).$$

I attempted to prove it but wasn't able to and I want to know if this is true in general.

**edit:** As was pointed out, the argument obviously does not work when $a = 1$ and most of my experiment assumed $a = 2$ since it is the easiest. But I still suspect that my conjecture holds when $a \neq 1$.

Comment: Have you checked the results with $a = 1$?

Comment: @JohnOmielan That is a good point, but I suspect that my conjecture still holds when $a \neq 1$.

Comment: Then how about, more generally, with $a = k(mn) + 1$ for any integer $k$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When $\gcd(m,n) \ne 1$, no such formula can hold, because $\mathrm{ord}_m(a)$ and $\mathrm{ord}_n(a)$ do not necessarily determine $\mathrm{ord}_{mn}(a)$.

For example, take $m=15$ and $n=21$. Then:

- $\mathrm{ord}_{15}(8) = 4$, $\mathrm{ord}_{21}(8) = 2$, and $\mathrm{ord}_{15\cdot 21}(8) = 4$.
- $\mathrm{ord}_{15}(13) = 4$, $\mathrm{ord}_{21}(13) = 2$, but $\mathrm{ord}_{15 \cdot 21}(13) = 12$.

What we know is that if $a^k \equiv 1 \pmod{mn}$, then $a^k \equiv 1 \pmod m$ and $a^k \equiv 1 \pmod n$; therefore $\mathrm{ord}_m(a) \mid \mathrm{ord}_{mn}(a)$ and $\mathrm{ord}_n(a) \mid \mathrm{ord}_{mn}(a)$; hence $$\mathrm{lcm}(\mathrm{ord}_n(a), \mathrm{ord}_m(a)) \mid \mathrm{ord}_{mn}(a).$$ But the quantity $\frac{\mathrm{ord}_{mn}(a)}{\mathrm{lcm}(\mathrm{ord}_n(a), \mathrm{ord}_m(a))}$ can vary.